# Sigil cannot edit book and no code view or book view

Tags: ebook

I am trying to get someone to help me edit a book on sigil.  However the Mac menu is different for her.

She does not have a menu option for code-view and book-view.  It is in the view took bar which does not exist.

I really don't understand Macs and it was a big problem just to get her menu to show.
She is in China and I am in Myanmar so I cannot play with her computer..  Is there a reason why this is not working.

A YouTube video has these menus.
The most recent file was downladed from GitHub.

Maybe the file is read only or does not have rights when I sent her a file from my Linux computer?

[image]